# Lack of work, should I be worried about my position?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment

As the title states.

There is an extreme lack of work for me, to the point where I have done no more than maybe 30 minutes worth of work in 3 days. At first it was just annoying as I like being productive and it's not as if I can keep my self busy at work, so I mostly just sit around reading up on things improving on older sites I've done.

Some things to note about my employer. I'm not allowed to work on any of my own projects, even if it's meant to benefit the company to a degree as idy be able to use it for us later on. Also they have a problem with watching any kind of video, including learning material.

I'm not sure if I should be scared for my job as everyone who works in or close to our department knows that.I don't have work anymore. I've run out of ways to try and seem proactive. And I try to study new things via documents but there's only so much learning you can do in a day.

Any advice?

Also note: I have asked for more work. I am waiting on a lot of things at the moment. Also another colleague had the same issue and indicated it to one of the bosses. They have been retrenched (laid off).

I know this is a temporary thing, but I'm scared bringing it to light will make it seem like a permanent thing and i'lly just be retrenched as well.

Clarification:
"Retrenchment is a form of dismissal due to no fault of the employee, it is a process whereby the employer reviews its business needs in order to increase profits or limit losses, which leads to reducing its employees"

Comment: Since rocking the boat can get you "retrenched" (what does that mean?), why not just continue doing what you are doing and highlight the issue to your boss while reading up on tech?

Comment: "Retrenchment is a form of dismissal due to no fault of the employee, it is a process whereby the employer reviews its business needs in order to increase profits or limit losses, which leads to reducing its employees", Well that is the question will me continuing to do as such lead to me being Retrenched, Well to explain my Senior Structure at work its In Essence me -> "Manager" -> CEO but nothing that goes threw to the Manager doesnt get to the CEO so in highlighting this will more then likely be the same as Rocking the boat

Comment: @JustSomeone based on the comments I've updated the question a bit so it's more clear to everyone, feel free to revert if you disagree with the change!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unassigned at work for weeks because of poor management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/127821/unassigned-at-work-for-weeks-because-of-poor-management)

Answer (score 9):

Only advice I can think of is to *propose* work rather than ask for it.

Think of something you think you could be doing, design a project, put together a proposal, send your boss a summary with a question that they can just reply "yes" to.

Ideally you could just start *doing* the work but you've indicated that the company doesn't like that, so this is the best I can recommend.

Comment: Interesting, So maybe look into something beneficial for the company and try and pitch that?

Comment: Pretty much. Rather than say "hey boss, I have nothing to do, can you think of something", which creates a problem for them that they need to solve, say "hey boss, I've been looking into X. I could do Y that will help us by [...]. Unless something else comes up, am I alright to go work on that?". Which takes more effort to refuse than to just let you get on with it. Given the company's position, try to make sure it will not cost anything (ideally including other people's time) and will either bring in revenue, reduce losses, or do something else that is clearly value-add.

Comment: I once encountered a consultancy firm that advertised itself to potential clients on the basis that it had no internal projects.  I wonder whether this company has done something similar and is now finding keeping its word dangerously constraining?

Comment: @JustSomeone " Im not allowed to work on any of my own projects, Even if its meant to benefit the company to a degree as id be able to use it for us later on." Jup, make your projects company projects. THey're paying you already so even if they won't use it won't be any different than what it is now. And if they will use it. Kudos for you.

Answer (score -1):

> Some things to note about my Employer. Im not allowed to work on any
> of my own projects

Doing so would likely turn over the IP created in those personal projects over to the company, so it's good that you are not doing so as they would not be yours anymore.

> I'm not sure if I should be scared for my job as everyone who works in
> or close to our department knows that.I dont have work anymore I've
> run out of ways to try and seem proactive.

From the sound of it you should be very worried, not only you sit most of the days twiddling your thumbs, but also no one seems to care - despite knowing that this is going on. This is about as big as red flags get, and a sign that you need to start hunting for a new job right away. Maybe by the time you will get an offer things will improve, but it seems as probably that eventually you will be let go instead.

> I know this is a temporary thing but im scared bringing it to light
> will make seem like a permanent thing and i'll just be retrenched as
> well.

If this seems like an actual risk that bringing this to light may get you fired then you must make a choice - either take the risk (which can come in many forms - creating work for yourself, helping your boss/manager to create work etc) and do so because you care about the company more than you worry about possibly getting fired; or say nothing until you can find a new job somewhere else. Going the risk route can benefit you, and the company, you may get praised for showing your initiative, but then the risk is clearly that you will get fired. You have to make your own choices around that, but I certainly would start looking for a new job ASAP.

Comment: Two downvotes, not a single comment. Woot woot.